# Temporarily ignore the "Hide Ignore Tags" settings by means of a URL query string

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I have lots of ignore tags - but once in a while, I happen to see a question of interest flash on screen just briefly which I'd like to investigate.

Yes - I know - I can go to my profile, prefs, then turn off the "Hide Ignored Tags", and go back to the page the question was on. It's just **very tedious** to do so (and then turn it back on after I'm done).

What I'd *really like to see* is a query string parameter - something like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest&ignore=false
                                                     *************
```

or something like that, to quickly turn off the "hide ignored tags" feature for this one page view, without having to fiddle around with my preferences and go through lots of clicks and pages to get the behavior I am looking for.

Any hope something like that my be implemented some time?

Comment: This would be awesome. Meanwhile, I hit Esc as soon as my browser begins displaying questions as the page loads, so scripts get stopped and posts with ignored tags don't get hidden.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: that requires **very fast** brain, eye and hand coordination :-) Not always feasible at my age :-)